# How to make a custom boolproperty control an operator?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm trying to create an *Operator* and I was wondering what code to use to specifically toggle the *Operator*? I'm working on with a checkbox (`BoolProperty`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)

Comment: The checkbox can be displayed as toggle `layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool", toggle=True)`. In addition to the post rjg linked to, have a look into: [Quickest way to create panel buttons with quick functionality](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146417/quickest-way-to-create-panel-buttons-with-quick-functionality/146439#146439)

Comment: That is true but what I need is a way for the bool property to affect the operator first

Comment: A bool property that affects the operator? What do you mean by that? @ScottieDoria In other words: You can't toggle an operator (read the post I've linked). However you can use a bool property as part of an operator along with a scene property (synced state) the user can toggle before executing it. Is that what you want?

Comment: can you share an example script of what your're mentioning?

Comment: Can you please try to explain what you mean? To solve your issue here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/150522/31447 ? @ScottieDoria

Comment: [blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119211](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119211/) this is what I found which may be the closest from what I want. Unfortunately the script was never updated or a proper fix provided and I can't seem to make it work according to the discussion. @brockmann

Answer (score 3):

You can access the values of all properties (almost). The following *Operator* prints the current state (`True`, `False`) of a custom scene property called `my_bool` which is displayed at the top of the panel:

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )

from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Scene Properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyProperties(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Operators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        if mytool.my_bool:
            print ("Bool Property enabled")
        else:
            print ("Bool Property disabled")

        return {'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool")
        layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname)

        state_txt = "enabled" if mytool.my_bool else "disabled"
        layout.label(text="Bool Property {}".format(state_txt))

        layout.separator()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    MyProperties,
    SimpleOperator,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Layout code ripped from: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)